# JQuery Code is not getting executed after integrating with HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am automating a process wherein I have to login to [website](https://www.shipper-ml.com/viewReports.do) and download only the CSV files from the different types of files.

My jQuery code is getting executed in the console but not getting executed after integrating with HTML. Please find the jQuery code below :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(window).on("load", function() {
   $('.ibody tr').each(function(a, b) {
   var count = 0;
   var name = $('.cl', b).text();
   if (name.indexOf(".CSV") !== -1 && name.indexOf("TAS") !== -1) {
   var d = a - 9;
   var hiddenIFrameID = 'hiddenDownloader' + count++;
   var iframe = window.createElement('iframe');
   iframe.id = hiddenIFrameID;
   iframe.style.display = 'none';
   window.body.appendChild(iframe);
            iframe.src = "https://www.shipper-ml.com/viewReports.do?ctrl=reportListForDownload&action=DownloadReport&param=" + d;
          }
        });
      });
    
  </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Firstly, remove one of the nested window.load event handlers. Secondly, check the console for errors.

Comment: Is `$(window).on("load", function() {
      $(window).on('load', function() {` intentional in your code or is it typo?

Comment: why you need two onload function that too one inside other?

Comment: $('.ibody tr') there is not such selector in your body

Comment: try replacing `window` with `document` everywhere

Comment: where is your tbody?

Comment: Can you add HTML also.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan and PM, nested window.load event handlers is a typo.. I have cremoveed it. I have checked in console, there is no error. It's giving the correct output in console

Comment: @Mithun G, I have tried it, but no success

Comment: @NegiRox, tbody is the classname of the table from where the file is getting downloded

Comment: Are you trying to access HTML of iframe content? i mean the query selector of `tbody`

Comment: if so then you might have to check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frames for accessing frames elements

Comment: @Manjunath, I guess the issue is with the HTML part and not Jquery because Jquery part is giving the correct output when executed in Chrome console

Comment: @ShubhamGupta, how shoud I give that selector in body ? 
Actually I am new to Jquery so facing difficulty while integration

Comment: Actually you are accessing the body Elements , in you code you are trying to access `tr` tag which is not present in body.

Comment: use setTimeout to handle this

Comment: @NegiRox there is no use of setTimeout as he is iterating through `tr` upon which iframe is included based on its result.

Comment: @Manjunath, so how should I go ahead ?

Comment: @Shivangi If you can tell us what you are trying to achieve exactly we can help you.

Comment: @Manjunath, I am automating a process wherein I have to login to website and download only the CSV files from the different types of files. My jQuery code is getting executed in the console but not getting executed after integrating with HTML. Please find the code in the question.

Comment: @Shivangi Can you try using a Plunkr or GitHub repo to put your code, I'll try to take a look at it and may be help you?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman, if you could give me your mail id, i can mail you the complete code

Comment: @Shivangi It's there in my [profile page](https://praveen.science/). `:)`

Comment: I have mailed you the code. Please have a look :(

Comment: Can somebody please help me :(

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I was, indeed, off-base with this. Didn't read your code carefully.

leaving this here for historical purposes...

I might be completely off-base with my assumptions here, and apologize in advance if this is the case. That said, it really looks like you are trying to load a page inside an IFrame and use jQuery outside of the IFrame to read data from inside the IFrame.

Long story short: you cannot use jQuery (or any javascript, or, indeed, ANYTHING AT ALL, if the browsers are working as they should) to manipulate or read content that is inside an IFrame, from outside the IFrame, **if that IFrame has a src tag**.

You can only manipulate / read from iframe you have built from scratch by yourself. This is by design, and for an important security reason. If you want to use IFrame to display a page, you are severely restricted to only show the page to user as-is.

If my assumption was correct, you need to either:

1. Get your JavaScript embedded (nicely) into the page you are now loading in your IFrame or
2. Use an AJAX call to get the contents of that page into your current page's memory context. This will probably mean jumping through some hoops if you really want to use jQuery to find all the elements you want.
3. ...or, you may be able to create an empty IFrame, put the content you got from the AJAX call into that IFrame along with your Javascript, and get it to work. maybe. Not sure about this one.

Comment: Can you help me on how to do this ? How to do AJAX call ?

Comment: @Shivangi That would be far too much to do in this space, and there are lots of online tutorials on that matter. However, I would like to ask for clarification, and since my reputation makes me unable to make comments on anywhere else but my own questions and answers, I'll ask here:

Into WHICH html have you so far tried to put this JavaScript/jQuery code of yours? Have you placed this javascript into the page that has those `.ibody tr` elements? (And not by chrome console, but by editing the page that comes from the server?)

Answer (score -1):

can you please try with this? replace your window.createElement with document.createElement .

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ibody tr').each(function(a, b) {
    var count = 0;
    var name = $('.cl', b).text();
    if (name.indexOf(".CSV") !== -1 && name.indexOf("TAS") !== -1) {
    var d = a - 9;
    var hiddenIFrameID = 'hiddenDownloader' + count++;
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.id = hiddenIFrameID;
    iframe.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.src = "https://www.shipper-ml.com/viewReports.do?ctrl=reportListForDownload&action=DownloadReport&param=" + d;
      }
    });
  })
```

Comment: can you please tell me that if  .ibody is a class name then where it is in html form?

Comment: I am not sure how to give that ? should i give it in div tag ? Can you please help me with that ?

Comment: Should I give something like this in body tag : <form action="#" method="post" name="form_name" class="ibody" >

Comment: where is .ibody tr in your html form... i can't see in your given example

Comment: It's not there... I have not added it as I don't know how to add it exactly

Comment: then your code will not execute because it is not finding that element

Comment: Can you please help me in adding html form ?

Comment: if you can able to share your code or environment where i can test... then yes

Comment: Can you give me your personnel mail id ? I can mail you the complete code.

Comment: mukeshsingh.negi007@gmail.com

Comment: I have mailed you the entire code. Please have a look and help me !

Comment: Were you able to spot the issue ?

Comment: mailed you please check

Comment: Same problem with that code also. It's running fine in Chrome console but not getting executed once integrated with HTML :( :(

Comment: What should I give in body tag ? Please help me :(

Comment: <body>
        <table class="ibody">
  <tbody>
  <tr class="header">
  <td>Report ID</td>
  <td>Report Type</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
    </body>
Are you asking me to do this ?

Comment: Please help as it's urgent

Comment: Hey NegiRox, can you please help ?